# Quaternions act like euler

Tags: java, 3d, rotation, lwjgl, quaternions

What is wrong with my implementation of quaternions? I think they still act like euler with gimbal locks and everything.

```
Quaternionf rotations = makeQuaternion(new Vector3f(1, 0, 0), angles.x);
            rotations.mul(makeQuaternion(new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), angles.y));
            rotations.mul(makeQuaternion(new Vector3f(0, 0, 1), angles.z));

Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();

matrix.translate(position);
matrix.rotate(rotations);
matrix.scale(scale);
```

The `angles` contains euler angles. People always tell me that I shouldn't use them at all but I have no idea how I would change the value of quaternion. And I think the `Quaternionf rotations` is correct. Eg. with angles `0, 90, 0` the quaternion contains `0.00, 0.707, 0.00, 0.707 (x,y,z,w)`. Which is correct right?

So where is the problem? I have read like everything I have found about this subject but I clearly still don't get it.

**EDIT:**

```
private static Quaternionf makeQuaternion(Vector3f n, float a) {

    float w, x, y, z; 

    a = a / 360 * (float) Math.PI * 2;

    w = (float) Math.cos(a / 2);

    x = (float) (n.x * Math.sin(a / 2));
    y = (float) (n.y * Math.sin(a / 2));
    z = (float) (n.z * Math.sin(a / 2));

    Quaternionf quaternion = new Quaternionf(x, y, z, w);

    return quaternion;

}
```

Comment: *"What is wrong with my implementation of quaternions?"* - we cannot tell since you have not shown *your* implementation of quaternions.

Comment: @luk2302 Well I think that is the most important part of it. I can give you the `makeQuaternion` function but as I said I think it gives the right result.

Comment: Are you normalizing your quaternions?

Comment: @NickClark No I am doing everything you see there. I tried normalizing them and it made no difference.

Comment: Okay, they should definitely be normalized.  I don't know enough about quaternions to make an educated response, but I would definitely recommend looking up the GLM or JOML implementation to see how it is done by those libraries.

Comment: @NickClark This is using JOML...

Comment: @httpdigest So how do I define changes in orientation by differential rotations?

Answer (score 1):

Quaternions seem very deceptive and it is very, very hard to get a solid feel for them.

First, a few resources you may have already read. The Wikipedia page for quaternions is a great resource for the equations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation

I also have a blog post on the basics about quaternions and what helped me get a feel for them: 
https://blog.mide.com/quaternions-for-orientation

There are a few things that look weird in makeQuaternion, and it is unclear if you are using things incorrectly, or just applying pieces in different places.

The equation you're implementing is:

[image: quaternion equation]

Here, A is the total angle of rotation, which is the rotation you would apply if you did the total rotation around a single axis, and Bx, By, Bz are direction angles. The sum of the square of the cosines of the direction angles needs to be 1 (ie cos^2 Bx + cos^2 By + cos^2 Bz = 1), because it represents a vector pointing from the origin.

You use n.x, n.y, n.z, and that will work as long as you make sure the sum of the squares = 1, ie they need to be points on a unit sphere. There is a similar relationship between A and the direction angles, but the easiest way to verify that is to make sure the sum of the squares of the quaternion = 1.

Comment: I have 2 quaternions. One is the orientation of the object and the other one is temporary containing the current orientation change. The temporary one's x+y+z+w is like 1.01 after normalizing and the main one is jumping between -2 and 2. These two quaternions are multiplied together.

Comment: If you're using makeQuaternion and the result is -2 to +2, then that means your a and n values are unreasonable. If the n values pass the sum of cosine squared test, then it must be the a value. 1.01 could just be a rounding error

Also, make sure you are multiplying correctly using the ijk vectors. if Q1 has X = 1, and Q2 has Y = 1, then Q1*Q2 = (Z=1)

Comment: What should they be? They only rule I'm following there that the angle is between 0 and 360. And the axis's values are between 0 and 1. Eg. rotating 90 around y-axis: makeQuaternion(new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), 90).

Comment: Sorry, that comment got posted a bit early, edited it up to add some info :)

Comment: Actually I just noticed makeQuaternion doesn't work at all. It's the one resulting between -2 and +2.